# Use Azure custom-vision trained model with tensorflow.js

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, tensorflow.js

I've trained a model with Azure Custom Vision and downloaded the TensorFlow files for Android 
(see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-your-model). How can I use this with [tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org)?

I need a model (pb file) and weights (json file). However Azure gives me a .pb and a textfile with tags.

From my research I also understand that there are also different pb files, but I can't find which type Azure Custom Vision exports.

I found the [tfjs converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter). This is to convert a TensorFlow SavedModel (is the *.pb file from Azure a SavedModel?) or Keras model to a web-friendly format. However I need to fill in "output_node_names" (how do I get these?). I'm also not 100% sure if my pb file for Android is equal to a "tf_saved_model".

I hope someone has a tip or a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Just parroting what I said [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7192#issuecomment-535747116) to save you a click. I do hope that the option to export directly to tfjs is available soon.

These are the steps I did to get an exported TensorFlow model working for me:

1. Replace PadV2 operations with Pad. This python function should do it. `input_filepath` is the path to the .pb model file and `output_filepath` is the full path of the updated .pb file that will be created.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def ReplacePadV2(input_filepath, output_filepath):
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with open(input_filepath, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    for node in graph_def.node:
        if node.op == 'PadV2':
            node.op = 'Pad'
            del node.input[-1]
            print("Replaced PadV2 node: {}".format(node.name))

    with open(output_filepath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

2. [Install tensorflowjs **0.8.6**](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflowjs/0.8.6/) or earlier. Converting frozen models [is deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/tree/master/tfjs-converter) in later versions.
3. When calling the convertor, set `--input_format` as `tf_frozen_model` and set `output_node_names` as `model_outputs`. This is the command I used.

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_json=true --output_node_names='model_outputs' --saved_model_tags=serve  path\to\modified\model.pb  folder\to\save\converted\output
```

Ideally, `tf.loadGraphModel('path/to/converted/model.json')` should now work (tested for tfjs 1.0.0 and above).

Comment: UPDATE: The feature to export directly to TensorFlowJS is now part of the most recent API version.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Trying to achieve the same thing - here is the start of an answer - to make use of the output_node_names:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_node_names='model_outputs' model.pb web_model
```

I am not yet sure how to incorporate this into same code - do you have anything @Kasper Kamperman?

Comment: maybe this article can help https://www.javascriptjanuary.com/blog/artificial-intelligence-in-javascript-with-tensorflowjs . for loading the model you would need to do smth similar to : mounted: async function () {
        ... other things...

        // load model
        const MODEL = 'model/tensorflowjs_model.pb';
        const WEIGHTS = 'model/weights_manifest.json';
        this.model = await tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL, WEIGHTS);
    }

Comment: See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7192#issuecomment-535747116 for a solution - I am hoping the author will add their own answer